# Hide and show Report region when no data found

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex-5

I'm using APEX 5 page to show a classic report region, I want to hide this region when no data found. 
I used javascript code in Page HTML Header but it's not working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var has_rows = document.getElementById('news_region').rows;
            if (has_rows==0){
        $("news_region").hide();
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a simple option is to use region's "Server-side condition" whose type is "Rows returned", while the SQL query is just the same as report region's query.

It works OK, no doubt in that, but I don't know it'll behave when the query is *heavy* (returns a lot of rows, selects from huge tables and stuff). Though, I presume it won't cost much to try it.

Comment: Or use a simplistic version of the report region's query - do not select any columns in the query, other than  a `select 'x' as info` column, retain your tables and join criteria, and add to the where clause `where rownum < 5` on the end to limit the impact of a full-blown report query.